# Can I see the list of ads previously shown on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I want see an ad that YouTube showed me days ago. Can I do that? How?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for your reply but that will not work because Youtube not show the same ads when you reload a video (web page).

Comment: @pnuts Thanks again for your reply. Seen then that at Youtube UI dont exist a way to list ads shown to an users ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most obvious answer for this would be "there is no element for this in any UI, so this isn't possible".

However: [We know that Google stores previous interactions with ads.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3181017?hl=en#) And thanks to privacy laws, Google is required to tell what data it stores about us. Now, there isn't any element regarding this on Google Takeout, but you can use [this contact form](https://support.google.com/policies/contact/sar) (or, once GDPR in in practice, contact their data protection officer) to get the data.

Comment: I just used this form to ask for a recent ad delivered via youtube.  We'll see what they provide, if anything.

Answer (score 0):

https://myadcenter.google.com/?ref=my-activity&hl=en

See Your recent ads section at the bottom of the page. There you find a list of ads you have been presented with recently.